# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.FormTag

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

Title error occures when I try to execute my index.jsp with taglibs

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>

<%@ taglib prefix="sf" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
```

Maven dependencies

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Also I have included .jar lib to `WEB-INF/lib/`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you include the `spring-core` dependency? Spring MVC will not work without it. It can be found [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core/4.2.4.RELEASE).

Comment: yep it's there, but not working.

Comment: Please check @LokeshRathor answer; he is correct. Remove the extra `>` on _LINE 34_

Comment: already removed, it's not a problem...Reuploaded image, now there is no extra >, error exist.

Comment: but error changed from spring to LogFactory. I have added extr >, but error don't changed back to spring...

Comment: This new error implies that `commons-logging` version _1.2_ is missing. Here is a [link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2).

Comment: yeah now added it too. and again some more such errors)

Comment: @WilliamCallahan now it's ok finally), thanks you was helpful

Answer (score 1):

Normally in JSP at the top we add the page directive as

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
```

Which should make sure that the form taglib is being loaded in the JSP.

Answer (score 0):

you have added one extra **>** at the end of line 34.